# Upgraded from Acces 2003 to Access 2010, code not working to read emails in Outlook 2010

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, outlook

In Access 2003 this code worked. We upgraded to Windows 7 and Access 2010/Outlook 2010.

This is the original code however, I have modified it multiple times using recommendations from sites like this.

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Applicaitoin
Dim Inbox as Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim InboxItems As OutLook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set myFolder1 = Session.Folders("Public Folders")
Set myFolder2 = myFolder1.Folders("All Public Folders")
Set myFolder3 = myFolder2.Folders("Europe")
Set myFolder4 = myFolder3.Folders("Naples")
Set myFolder5 = myFolder4.Folders("FSSA Naples IT"
Set Inbox = myFolder5.Folders("CDO")

Set InboxItems = Inbox.Items
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 "Public Folders" is different.

Set myFolder1 = Session.Folders("Public Folders - NameOfMailboxHere")